# MakeTableView to execute

Tags: arcpy

MakeTableView has been failed when I tried to open a tableview with more than 1.5 million records. Does anyone has solution of it? I tried to narrow down the returned results by putting where condition. Still I am getting the same error.

```
from arcpy.management import MakeTableView
from arcpy import management
from common.basetype import BaseType
from common.gisutils.exceptions import CreateTableViewError, DeleteTableViewError
from common.gisutils.errormessages import error_messages


class TableViewUtil(BaseType):
    """
    Creates a table view for CRUD data.
    """

    def __init__(self, str_working_layer_url: str, str_working_layer_id: str):
        self.working_layer_url = str_working_layer_url
        self.working_layer_id = str_working_layer_id

    @property
    def working_layer_id(self):
        return self._str_working_layer_id

    @working_layer_id.setter
    def working_layer_id(self, value: str):
        if not value:
            raise ValueError(error_messages.WORKING_LAYER_ID_REQUIRED)
        self._str_working_layer_id = value

    @property
    def working_layer_url(self):
        return self._str_working_layer_url

    @working_layer_url.setter
    def working_layer_url(self, value: str):
        if not value:
            raise ValueError(error_messages.WORKING_LAYER_REQUIRED)
        self._str_working_layer_url = value

    def create_table_view(self, str_view_name: str, str_where_clause: str = None):
        """
        Creates table view
        :param str_view_name: table view name
        :param str_where_clause:
        :return: None
        """
        if not str_view_name:
            raise ValueError(error_messages.TABLE_VALUE_NAME_REQUIRED)
        try:
            if str_where_clause:
                MakeTableView(
                    in_table=f"{self.working_layer_url}/{self.working_layer_id}",
                    out_view=str_view_name,
                    where_clause=str_where_clause,
                )
            else:
                MakeTableView(
                    in_table=f"{self.working_layer_url}/{self.working_layer_id}",
                    out_view=str_view_name,
                )
        except Exception as e:
            raise CreateTableViewError(
                str_table_view_name=str_view_name,
                str_working_layer_id=self.working_layer_id,
                str_working_layer_url=self.working_layer_url,
                message=e,
            )

    def delete_table_view(self, str_view_name: str):
        """Delete Table view"""
        if not str_view_name:
            raise ValueError(error_messages.TABLE_VALUE_NAME_REQUIRED)
        try:
            management.Delete(in_data=str_view_name)
        except Exception as e:
            raise DeleteTableViewError(
                str_table_view_name=str_view_name,
                str_working_layer_id=self.working_layer_id,
                str_working_layer_url=self.working_layer_url,
                message=e,
            )
```

if here I use this class like

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  obj_table_view = TableViewUtil(str_working_url = "featureserverurl", str_working_layer_id= 'layerid')
 obj_table_view.create_table_view(str_view_name="test_view")
```

I am getting an error like

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (MakeTableView).
```

Comment: Does it work in ArcGIS Desktop or Pro?  Can you create a small subset of the data in a new table and then does arcpy work on that smaller data set?  Post your script (or preferably the smallest possible version of a script that can cause the error to occur).  What is the actual error, or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @user2856 ; I am using branch versioning and feature server to work on a task.  An error is usually come when the tables records are more than 1.5 million.

Comment: The temporary solution I have applied is to minimize the data using where_clause of makeviewtable function. So when I only want to add data, I use "OBJECTID=-1" and when I want to update, delete, get, at that time, I use where_clause with proper condition so I can get those data which I need to modify or delete.